# Dielectric constant (relative permittivity)

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I recently learned that the dielectric constant (or relative permitivity) is not actually a constant, but it depends on wavelength or frequency (dielectric function). If that is the case, why are we taught in an introductory EM class that the dielectric constant is constant? When we say that the dielectric constant is 11.68 for silicon, which wavelength are we referring to?

When we perform a calculation that requires a knowledge of dielectric constant, which value (corresponding to which wavelength) do we use? For example, calculation of the width of space charge region requires us to know a dielectric constant of material.

\${\displaystyle w\approx \left[{\frac {2\epsilon _{r}\epsilon _{0}}{q}}\left({\frac {N_{A}+N_{D}}{N_{A}N_{D}}}\right)\left(V_{bi}-V\right)\right]^{\frac {1}{2}}}\$

I am very confused. Please help!

Comment: You've asked 10 question of which I see 5 that have been adequately answered so why haven't you formally accepted any answers yet? You got to pay the man!

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I forgot! I've just accepted all the answers.

Comment: The wavelength or the frequency will be the frequency of operation of the material. Usually below the relaxation frequency of the dielectric the relative permittivity is approximately constant. Read here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_spectroscopy)

Comment: @sarthak Thanks! So, is the dielectric constant used in calculation of depletion width referring to the real part of dielectric function at 0 Hz?

Comment: At low frequencies only the real part contributes to the overall permittivity. By low frequencies, I mean the frequencies which are smaller than the relaxation frequency including 0Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the concept is easier to teach & grasp, and the equations easier to work with, if it's assumed "constant".

When learning about diodes, we simplify them - say they're "non-conducting below 0.7V" and "conducting above 0.7V", but that's not really true is it?  They have a highly non-linear range of conductivity.   But taking that into account makes circuit analysis ALOT harder, so usually we ignore that fact.

One of the secrets to being a successful engineer IMO is knowing when you have to consider the secondary effects, and when using a simpler model suffices.

If considering the wavelength dependency of the dielectric 'constant' only changes ones answers by, say, 0.1% (just throwing out a number here, don't read too much into it...)  and we have a circuit full of 10% tolerance capacitors, does that error really matter???

On the other hand, if Einstiens relativity weren't accounted for, GPS accuracy would noticeably suffer.  Very small effect there (time dilation... time moves a hair faster for satellites than it does for us earthbound folks), but over the large distances involved, it becomes a noticeable error.

The Scientist says "This value is 1.09482 +- 0.00002"

The mathematician says "This value is 1.094829384929375092835012084376917349509345..... to infinity"

The engineer says "Eh... 1.1 is close enough"

Comment: You are incorrect. The dielectric constant does have a strong dependence on frequency. Read about dielectric spectroscopy.

Comment: You entirely missed my point. The question was "Why do we say it's constant".  I said, "It's constant unless the fine details matter".      At microwave frequencies, yes it matters.  For us mere mortals it doesn't.    That's all I meant, nothing more.  I thought I was adequately clear about that.

Comment: Dielectric constant of water is 81 at 2.4 GHz and only 1.6 at optical 500 THz. And it even changes across the optical wavelengths - think of a rainbow :)